# Highlight UITableViewCell while pickerview event

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UI which contains a UITableView and a UIDatePicker. When I select a Row on my table it is highlighted, but as soon as I interact with the DatePicker (scroll to a new value) the row isn't highlighted anymore. The value of the row is bound to that of the DatePicker. How can I permanently highlight the cell?

In the iCal-App -> Add -> Start&End I saw this behaviour. 
I tried the selectRowAtIndex method in my ValueChanged-method of the picker. I thought that the highlighting is lost in this callback-method.

```
-(IBAction)setStartTimeMethod
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd. MMM yyyy  HH:mm"];


    if(!self.endDateRowSelected)
        self.date = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];
    else
        self.endDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];
    [dateFormat release];
//    [self.tableView1 selectRowAtIndexPath:tableView1.indexPathForSelectedRow animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    [self.tableView1 reloadData];

}
```

Edit, my didSelectRowMethod

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd. MMM yyyy  HH:mm"];

    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        NSLog(@"Start");
        self.endDateRowSelected = NO;


        NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:self.date];
        [datePicker setDate:startDate animated:YES];

        //if(self.endDateRowSelected)
          //  [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

    }else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        NSLog(@"End");
        self.endDateRowSelected = YES;

        if(self.endDate){
            NSDate *endDateTime = [formatter dateFromString:self.endDate];
            [datePicker setDate:endDateTime animated:YES];
        }
    }else{
        self.endDateRowSelected = NO;
    }

    [formatter release];
//    Won't work, doesn't allow highlighting a cell.
//    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}
```

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite easy.

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I must call the `selectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
...
if(indexPath.row == 0){
                cell.description.text = [dict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.dateTime.text = self.startDate;

                if(!endDateRowSelected)
                    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]; 
            }else if(indexPath.row == 2){
                cell.description.text = [dict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.dateTime.text = self.endDate;
                if(endDateRowSelected)
                    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]; 
            }
...
```

The bool is set in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, depending on clicking on Start or End.
I still reload the table in my pickerValueChanged delegate.

Thank you for time & help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code in the end of didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method of table view,

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't allow highlighting of a row. I want the against part - highlighting a cell till I click on another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[self.tableView1 reloadData];
// and then
[self.tableView1 selectRowAtIndexPath:tableView1.indexPathForSelectedRow animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

I guess a much better way of doing this is with IBOutlets for each custom cell in your table. If you are editing the date for that cell, then why reload the entire table? If you have less number of cells, you can go ahead and create custom UITableViewCell, add labels and update only those labels from your UIDatePicker delegate callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```